# Subdivision surface modifier & topology

Tags: edges

I created this component see screenshot, but after applying subdivision surface modifier the whole surface was distorted. In previous projects, the edge split modifier helped me solve this, but in this particular case it doesn't work quite right. Is this a topology issue?

Thank you very much for all the comments :-)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it is a topology problem, subdivision surface doesn't work well with n-gons and edge-split won't help you around this since it only splits the edges at a given angle threshold.

Comment: Big topology problems. please upload the blend file so that we can show you the right topology.

Comment: Also, edge split should be placed after the subsurf generally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick coments! Here is the link to the file: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iFLNKE5lyT5rMgREcMm-J1wP5-rVB47c/view?usp=sharing)  @BarbodM

Comment: Honestly, I think the easiest way to fix your problem is to rebuild your mesh from scratch by following moonboots' method because it has really terrible geometry and you will not be able to work with this mesh in the future when you are texturing it, UV mapping it or adding modifiers etc. It's going to take a long time to clean up your mesh so instead, I think it`s best to start from the beginning...that is if you want to.

Comment: Sure, I understand, thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this topology instead?

[image]

Create an angle, bevel it:

[image]

Extrude faces along normals:

[image]

Extrude this part:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]

Bevel the edges in order to sharpen:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @moonboots ,  it's clearer now. So am I correct that for good topology, it is better, if it is a curve or a bevel for example, to have the same number of vertex on both sides?

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "the same number on vertices on both sides"

Comment: I apologize for the bad wording, @moonboots. Basically, I mean more of a balancing of the overall topology, or better a vertex linking, where the preferred shape is a quad.

Comment: it's generally better to have quads (it easier to work with and create less artefacts) but here for example I have a ngon and it's ok as long as it doesn't create artefacts